# Sequentially lower semicontinuity

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set with lipschitz boundary, How can we show that the functional defined by  $f:W^{1,p}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  $f(u)=\int_{\Omega}|Du|_{\mathbb{R}^N}^p$ 
is sequentialy weakly lower semicontinous

Comment: Did you mean to say that $f$ is sequentially _weakly_ lower semicontinous?

Comment: Yes this is what i meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functional is continuous and convex, hence, sequentially weakly lower semicontinuous.